# does my current implementation of a doubly linked list class require restructuring for iterator end() functionality?

Tags: c++, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I am afraid that my current implementation of a doubly linked list does not accommodate an iterator appropriately. My iterators end() function needs to start pointing to the node after tail in order to decrement through the list.
Of the course as I have my list currently designed tail->next will be null.

am I write in understanding that my first and tail pointers are "dummy nodes"?

I have tried making a third pointer but could not find an implementation that I believe would work considering that much like my pushBack function everything is designed to work with first and tail being constructed as nullptrs in my doublyLinkedList class.

I have been trying to figure out how to implement an extra dummy node--any solution will do.

I will show only the parts of my code I feel may be relevant.

```
struct node
{
    T data;
    node<T> * next;
    node<T> * prev;

    node() {
        next = nullptr;
        prev = nullptr;
    };
    node(T data, node<T> * next = nullptr, node<T> * prev = nullptr) 
        : data(data), next(next), prev(prev) {};
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    node<T> * first;
    node<T> * tail;
    int size;
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList&);
    void copy(const LinkedList&);
    void operator=(const LinkedList&);
    //void insert_end(T dat);
    void pushBack(T data);
    void pushFront(T data);
    void display();
    void displayRev();
    int getSize();

    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        node<T> * itr;
    public:

        Iterator(node<T> * itr = nullptr) : itr(itr){};

        Iterator& operator++();
        Iterator operator++(int);
        Iterator& operator--();
        Iterator operator--(int);

        T operator*();

        bool operator!=(LinkedList<T>::Iterator other);
        bool operator==(LinkedList<T>::Iterator & other);

        ~Iterator() {}
    };
/*BEGIN AND END*/
    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(first); }
    Iterator end(tail->next) 
    {
        return Iterator(tail->next); 
    }
    ~LinkedList();
};
```

definitions

```
template<class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator& LinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator--()
{

    itr = itr->prev;
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Iterator LinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator--(int)
{
    auto tmp = *this;

    itr = itr->prev;
    return tmp;
}

//constructor
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    first = tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
    /*node<T>* first = new node<T>;
    node<T>* tail = new node<T>;
    first->next = tail;
    tail->prev = first;*/

}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::pushBack(T data)
{

    if (first == nullptr)
    {
        first = tail = new node<T>(data);
        size++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (tail == nullptr)
        {
            tail = new node<T>(data);
            first->next = tail;
            tail->prev = first;
            size++;
        }
        else
        {
            node<T> *prevTail = tail;
            node<T> *newTail = new node<T>(data, nullptr, prevTail);
            prevTail->next = newTail;
            tail = newTail;
            size++;
        }
    }

}
```

main

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
typedef LinkedList<int>::Iterator iter;
int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> l1;
    l1.pushBack(10);
    l1.pushBack(20);
    l1.pushBack(30);

    for (auto itr = l1.begin(); itr != l1.end(); itr++)
    {
        std::cout << (*itr) << "  ";
    }
}
```

I have been at this for the past three hours to no avail, and have reverted back to where I started. If someone could show me the light I would be tremendously grateful.

thank you.

Comment: What problem are you encountering, exactly?  BTW, this *declaration* in the `LinkedList` class template looks like it would not compile:  `Iterator end(tail->next) `.

Comment: it would not because tail->next is null. I have edited my post to make this more clear.

Comment: Once again, what problem are you encountering, exactly?  Does the program fail to compile, or segfault at runtime, or produce incorrect results?

Comment: the problem is whe i decrement it doesnt print the first element in the list

Comment: the first element being '10'

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that I can see.  Both avoid the use of dummy nodes, although that would be a viable approach as well.

### Option 1: Make the iterator a forward-only iterator

Constructing an end iterator is difficult because the natural approach is to instantiate `Iterator{}`, which means that the `Iterator::itr` node pointer would be null.  BUT, the decrement operator would not be implementable in this case.  As a solution, those operations could be removed.

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
    /* ... */
    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        node<T> * itr;
    public:

        Iterator(node<T> * itr = nullptr) : itr(itr){};

        Iterator& operator++();
        Iterator operator++(int);

        T operator*();

        bool operator!=(LinkedList<T>::Iterator other);
        bool operator==(LinkedList<T>::Iterator & other);
    };
    Iterator begin() { return Iterator{first}; }    
    Iterator end() { return Iterator{}; }  
};
```

### Option 2:  Add a `prev` member to the iterator

I think you could add a `prev` pointer to the Iterator to retain the bidirectional operations.

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
    /* ... */
    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        node<T> * current;  // null if and only if this is end iterator.
        node<T> * prev;     // may be null (at head of list)
    public:
        Iterator() : current{nullptr}, prev{nullptr} {}
        Iterator(node<T> * current) : current{current}, prev{current ? current->prev : nullptr} {}
        Iterator(node<T> * current, node<T>* prev) : current{current}, prev{prev} {}

        Iterator& operator++();    // implemented using `curr`
        Iterator operator++(int);  // implemented using `curr`
        Iterator& operator--();    // implemented using `prev`
        Iterator operator--(int);  // implemented using `prev`

        T operator*();  // implemented using `curr`

        bool operator!=(LinkedList<T>::Iterator other);
        bool operator==(LinkedList<T>::Iterator & other);
    };

    Iterator begin() { return Iterator{first}; }    
    Iterator end() { return Iterator{nullptr, tail}; }
};
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do And thank you for your response, but since I am passing tail to prev and not tail->next won't the iterator still be start reading before the last node? I am also not sure how I would implement with prev, been trying to do what I feel makes sense.

Comment: I don't really understand the question you're asking in your comment.  Basically, in the Option 2 approach I am suggesting, the end iterator will be pointing at a position *past the final element* in the linked list.  So the iterator's `prev` pointer will be pointing at the last node in the linked list.